# Fetch API call for each item in a Jinja2 for loop

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch, jinja2

I'm currently stuck on a personal project where Im making Fetch API calls to get the audio src for a list of html audio tags.

The fetch call is triggered by an onclick event on the track. Though regardless of what track i click on, fetch calls /play_track/1/ and appends the audio player to only the first track. Any way to remedy this?

As you can see my index.html is basically just jinja2:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {% for track in tracks %}
        {% include '_post.html' %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Heres _post.html with the Fetch call: (Currently using an onclick event to call but will switch to onpageload)

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
            <img width="500px" height="500px" class="img-thumbnail thumb" src="{{ track.thumbnail }}" class="card-img" alt="{{ track.title }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-7">
            <div id="card-body" class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title h5-title">{{ track.title }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text p-artist">{{ track.artist }}</p>
                <p class="card-text p-uploaded-at"><small class="text-muted">Uploaded on {{ track.created_at.strftime('%b %m, %Y') }}</small></p>
                <p onclick="fetchURL(event)" id="track-id">{{ track.id }}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        function fetchURL(event) {

            tid = document.getElementById('track-id');
            track_id = tid.innerHTML;

            fetch(`${window.origin}/play_track/${track_id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.status);
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data.message.url);
                    createAudioPlayer(data);
                });
        }

        function createAudioPlayer(data) {

            let cardBody = document.getElementById('card-body');

            let audio = document.createElement('audio');
            audio.controls = true;

            let source = document.createElement('source');
            source.type = "audio/mpeg";
            source.src = data.message.url

            cardBody.append(audio);
            audio.prepend(source);
        };

    </script>
</div>
```

And here is the backend code: (Which im pretty sure if i tweak I can avoid Fetch all-together but thats another issue)

```
@bp.route('/play_track/<track_id>/')
def play_track(track_id):

    track = Track.query.filter_by(id=track_id).first()

    res = requests.get(track.audio)
    if not res.status_code == 200:
        return f'Status code: {res.status_code}'

    json_res = json.loads(res.text)
    mpeg_audio_url = json_res['url']

    msg_dict = {
        'url': mpeg_audio_url
    }

    res = make_response(jsonify({'message': msg_dict}))
    return res
```

To summarize: Fetch call not understanding Jinja2 for loop. Whether i click on track 1, 10, or 46, etc, It calls /play_track/1/ and appends the audio tag to the first track.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        function fetchURL(event) {
            tid = event.target;
            track_id = tid.innerHTML;

            fetch(`${window.origin}/play_track/${track_id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.status);
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data.message.url);
                    createAudioPlayer(data, event);
                });
        }
```

The problem was the first line. you weren't getting the current event target.
Ids are must be unique thus every time you loop through the track you create an element with the same id. Change **track-id** from **id** to **class**.

```
<p onclick="fetchURL(event)" class="track-id">{{ track.id }}</p>
```

Also since you were using document.getElementById() it would return the first occurrence of that id. That is the reason, it was returning track 1 constantly. 
Another thing, there is no point in having it loop the javascript over and over since the new ones would just override the old ones.

#### Fixed createAudioPlayer(), make sure to pass the event object into it. I already did it for you, so just copy the new fetchURL function.

```
        function createAudioPlayer(data, event) {

            let cardBody = event.target.parentElement;

            let audio = document.createElement('audio');
            audio.controls = true;

            let source = document.createElement('source');
            source.type = "audio/mpeg";
            source.src = data.message.url

            cardBody.append(audio);
            audio.prepend(source);
        };
```

Comment: This gives the right audio, but still appends it to the first track.

Comment: You are using document.getElementById. As I said it returns the first occurrence of that id, which is the first track.

Comment: I will fix it for you but make sure to  go learn about id's and classes, and the various dom functions.

Comment: I am not. I have fixed it to use getElementsByClassName('track-id')[0] and its now displaying the correct audio but only on the first track.

Comment: if you use getElementsByClassName("track-id"), it will return all the elements with that class as an array. Then if you add the [0] it gets the first element. see what i mean. you are still getting the first element in the end. You arent getting the correct one.

Comment: you have to get the specific element by either passing its track number into the createAudioPlayer function or passing the event in and using the current target function. Anyways i did it for you. Just make sure to read what I did so you understand it better.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced event.currentTarget() with event.target and got it to work. Appreciate it